# SQL Partition by to get sandwiched totals?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have a list of data that i want the running sums of between zeros. I thought I could do this with Partition by. 
So the example below

```
ID      Date          MyVar
2083    2016-04-20      1 --- 2
2083    2015-03-19      1 --- 1
2083    2015-01-20      0 ---- resets
2083    2014-12-15      1 ----4
2083    2014-11-10      1 ----3
2083    2014-10-22      1 ----2
2083    2014-10-07      1 ----1
2083    2014-09-11      0 ---- resets
2083    2014-08-01      1 ----1

select ID, Date,MyVar, sum(myvar) over (Partition by myVar order by ID,Date 
desc Range between unbounded preceding and current row)
from Table
where ID = 2083
order by ID, Date desc
```

Below is what I get

```
2083    2016-04-20  1   1
2083    2015-03-19  1   2
2083    2015-01-20  0   0
2083    2014-12-15  1   3
2083    2014-11-10  1   4
```

I realize that unbounded shouldn't work here but Range only works Unbounded and I'm not sure how to use it with Rows. Any Help would be appreciated. I can grab all the 0 Value Dates and sum MyVar between them in a stored Procedure but there has to be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Is `myvar` always either 1 or 0?

Comment: I'm more familiar with teradata, which includes the proprietary `RESET WHEN` clause in window for this kind of scenario. There was an article published just this week requesting this feature in tsql: http://m.sqlmag.com/software-development/t-sql-feature-request-add-reset-when-clause-reset-window-partition

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the rows into groups and then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when myvar > 0 then row_number() over (partition by grp, case when myvar > 0 then 1 else 2 end order by date)
        end) as newval
from (select t.*, sum(1 - myvar) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, there is something with your answer. http://rextester.com/QNWZS86561 The first group  start with 1, but the other group start with 2 because the null value. Of course I dont know what value want OP for the ***reset*** rows neither

Comment: select t.*,
       (case when myvar >= 0 then row_number() over (partition by grp order by date)
        end)-1  as newval
from (select t.*, sum(1 - myvar) over (order by date) as grp
      from #temp1 t
     ) t;

Answer (score 0):

while I write the code Gordon has been more quick, so bad for me hahaha:

```
    select 2083 as ID  , cast('2016-04-20' as date) as [Date], 1 as myVar  into #temp1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083   , '2015-03-19',      1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083,    '2015-01-20'      ,0

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083    ,'2014-12-15'      ,1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083    ,'2014-11-10'      ,1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083    ,'2014-10-22'      ,1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083    ,'2014-10-07'      ,1

    insert into #temp1
    select 2083    ,'2014-09-11'      ,0


    select t.ID, DATE, myvar,
       isnull((case when myvar > 0 then row_number() over (partition by grp order by date)
        end)-1,0)  as newval
from (select t.*, sum(1 - myvar) over (order by date) as grp
      from #temp1 t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that one, but then first one will start with 0 instead of 1